# Create a VBA version of dictionaries with 2 values per key

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make my excel macro dynamic. The excel macro essentially looks at only 2 columns, one which contains the name and the other contains the numeric part. I have my macro working perfectly, the only problem is that it is hard coded when I created the program. In my code, I hard coded the name in column 2 and the numeric part in column 3. However, that is not the case in real life. The name and numeric data could appear in column 1 and 5, for example. I've been manually rearranging the data in the columns so that it fits into what hard coded. However, I want to make this process dynamic and less manual work for the user.

There are 5 different versions of spreadsheets this macro will be used on and in each spreadsheet, the name and number columns are different. I am looking to make   a user form box of some sort, where the user selects "Vendor XYZ" and since Vendor XYZ always sends their data sheets the same way I know that Vendor XYZ's name column is 2 and number is 4. So I was thinking that the dictionary would be something in the form of {Vendor XYZ: 2,4}  (where the first number is the name column and the second number is the numeric columnnumber...I know the syntax is wrong)

I think my work around this would be to hard code the different vendors and then use if statements ( I haven't tried it yet)

I will have a user input/dropdown box of 5 different vendors. Then something like

```
If userinput="A" 
then namecol=2 and numcol=1
If userinput="B" 
then namecol="3" and numcol="4"
```

I don't know if that would even work. The problem with that is that the number of vendors is small now, but will be scaling up and I can't do that if we have 100 or 1000 vendors. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Showing your code is recommended here

Comment: Plus, if possible, try to summarize the problem in 2 sentences.

Comment: A common approach would be to use `Find` in row 1 to search for header labels that tell you which columns to use. This only works if all your vendors supply common terms like `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`.

Comment: pass them in as `dic.add key, array("item1","item2")`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie nope, they don't supply the same column names.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav How  would I refer to array item 1 or array item 2? Ex. namecol=  is the first item of the array? namecol would be an integer so that when I use Cells(x,y) later, I can use do something like Cells(x,colname). I'm also afraid of type mismatch errors.

Comment: `dic(key)(0)` or `dic(key)(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your initial dataset is retrieved, you can use something like this:

```
Public Function GetHeaderIndices(ByVal InputData As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    If IsEmpty(InputData) Then Exit Function

    Dim HeaderIndices As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set HeaderIndices = New Scripting.Dictionary

    HeaderIndices.CompareMode = TextCompare

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(InputData, 2) To UBound(InputData, 2)
        If Not HeaderIndices.Exists(Trim(InputData(LBound(InputData, 1), i))) Then _
           HeaderIndices.Add Trim(InputData(LBound(InputData, 1), i)), i
    Next

    Set GetHeaderIndices = HeaderIndices
End Function
```

This `Function` takes an array as an input and gives the user a dictionary with the indices of the headers from the input.

If you are *smart* (and I say this because too many users just don't use tables) you will have your data in a table, and you will have named that table. If you did, you could do something like this:

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Dim MyData as Variant
    MyData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet").ListObjects("MyTableName").Range.Value
End Sub
```

So, if you data looked like this:

```
Foo    Baz    Bar

1      Car    Apple
3      Van    Orange
2      Truck  Banana
```

The function would give you a dictionary like:

```
Keys        Items

Foo         1
Baz         2
Bar         3
```

Then your subroutines could do something like this:

```
Sub DoEverything()
    Dim MyData as Variant
    MyData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet").ListObjects("MyTableName").Range.Value

    DoSomething(MyData)
End Sub


Sub DoSomething(ByRef MyData as Variant)
    Dim HeaderIndices as Scripting.Dictionary
    Set HeaderIndices = GetHeaderIndices(MyData)

    Dim i as Long

    ' Loop through all the rows after the header row.
    For i = LBound(MyData, 1) + 1 to Ubound(MyData, 1)
        If MyData(i, HeaderIndices("Baz")) = "Truck" Then
            ?MyData(i, HeaderIndices("Foo"))
            ?MyData(i, HeaderIndices("Baz"))
            ?MyData(i, HeaderIndices("Bar"))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This does require a reference to Scripting.Runtime so if you don't want to add a reference you will need to change any reference to `As Scripting.Dictionary` to `As Object` and any `New Scripting.Dictionary` to `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.

Alternatively, I use the following code module to take care of adding references programmatically for all my users:

```
Public Sub PrepareReferences()
    If CheckForAccess Then
        RemoveBrokenReferences
        AddReferencebyGUID "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}"
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub AddReferencebyGUID(ByVal ReferenceGUID As String)
    Dim Reference As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set to continue in case of error
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Add the reference
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
        GUID:=ReferenceGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0

    ' If an error was encountered, inform the user
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 32813
        ' Reference already in use.  No action necessary
    Case vbNullString
        ' Reference added without issue
    Case Else
        ' An unknown error was encountered, so alert the user
        MsgBox "A problem was encountered trying to" & vbNewLine _
             & "add or remove a reference in this file" & vbNewLine & "Please check the " _
             & "references in your VBA project!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveBrokenReferences()
    ' Reference is a Variant here since it requires an external reference.
    ' It isnt possible to ensure that the external reference is checked when this process runs.
    Dim Reference As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Reference = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)
        If Reference.IsBroken Then
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove Reference
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function CheckForAccess() As Boolean
    ' Checks to ensure access to the Object Model is set
    Dim VBP As Variant
    If Val(Application.Version) >= 10 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Set VBP = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please pay attention to this message." _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Your security settings do not allow this procedure to run." _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "To change your security setting:" _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " 1. Select File - Options - Trust Center - Trust Center Settings - Macro Settings." & vbCrLf _
                 & " 2. Place a checkmark next to 'Trust access to the VBA project object model.'" _
                 & vbCrLf & "Once you have completed this process, please save and reopen the workbook." _
                 & vbCrLf & "Please reach out for assistance with this process.", _
                   vbCritical
            CheckForAccess = False
            Err.Clear
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    CheckForAccess = True
End Function
```

And I have the following command in each `Workbook_Open` event (less than ideal, but only good solution I have so far)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    PrepareReferences
End Sub
```